# Ruby ob Rails rake aborted

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails, openserver

```
    > rake db:migrate --trace
    rake aborted!
    NameError: undefined local variable or method `__dir__' for main:Object
    F:/OpenServer/domains/localhost/webrails/config/boot.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' F:/OpenServer/domains/localhost/webrails/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    F:/OpenServer/domains/localhost/webrails/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    F:/OpenServer/domains/localhost/webrails/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
    F:/OpenServer/domains/localhost/webrails/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
    C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
    C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
    C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

    C:/Ruby19/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    C:/Ruby19/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Использую openserver и win10

> rails -v
>   Rails 5.0.1
>
> gem -v
>   1.8.24
>
> rake
>   rake aborted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `__dir__`, на отсутствие которого он жалуется, отсутствует в Ruby 1.9.

И вообще, [Rails 5 требует Ruby версии не ниже 2.2.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html).

**Обновляйтесь.**